# convert matching pattern into row

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Hi I have a constraint file.

```
[get_ports {rdata[*]}] [get_ports {wdata[*]}] [get_ports {axirdata[*]}] [get_ports {raddr[*]}] [get_ports {waddr[*]}] [get_ports en] [get_ports {xyz[*]}] [get_ports err]
```

Above constraint is in single line. I want to convert it into column like,

```
[get_ports {rdata[*]}]

 [get_ports {wdata[*]}]

 [get_ports {axirdata[*]}]

 [get_ports {raddr[*]}]

 [get_ports {waddr[*]}]

 [get_ports en]

 [get_ports {xyz[*]}]

 [get_ports err]
```

I want to separate each [get_port port_name] into single one line column

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Not at all clear. Could you please do add more details along with your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: In constraints file it contains  [get_ports {rdata[*]}]  [get_ports {wdata[*]}]  [get_ports {axirdata[*]}]  [get_ports {raddr[*]}]  [get_ports {waddr[*]}]  [get_ports en] [get_ports {xyz[*]}]  [get_ports err] in a single line. I want to split it after every single [get_ports name] into single line (into first coloumn)

Comment: Comments are NOT meant for posting samples, as requested before kindly do edit your post with code tags.

Answer (score 1):

With a sed that understands `\n` as meaning  `a newline`:

```
$ sed 's/] *\[/]\n[/g' file
[get_ports {rdata[*]}]
[get_ports {wdata[*]}]
[get_ports {axirdata[*]}]
[get_ports {raddr[*]}]
[get_ports {waddr[*]}]
[get_ports en]
[get_ports {xyz[*]}]
[get_ports err]
```

With any sed:

```
sed 's/] *\[/]\
[/g' file
```

or any awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/] *\[/,"]\n[")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not clear, looks like you want to convert lines into a single to row.

```
paste -sd" "  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[get_ports {rdata[*]}] [get_ports {wdata[*]}] [get_ports {axirdata[*]}] [get_ports {raddr[*]}] [get_ports {waddr[*]}] [get_ports en] [get_ports {xyz[*]}] [get_ports err]
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed the samples of  input and expected output so adding following solution now.

```
awk '{gsub(/\] \[/,"]"ORS"[")} 1' Input_file
OR
awk '{gsub(/] /, "]" ORS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[get_ports {rdata[*]}]
[get_ports {wdata[*]}]
[get_ports {axirdata[*]}]
[get_ports {raddr[*]}]
[get_ports {waddr[*]}]
[get_ports en]
[get_ports {xyz[*]}]
[get_ports err]
```

Comment: @Vishal Patel, could you please try these and let me know then?

Comment: Hi Ravinder, it works fine.  Thanks. Can you explain it?

Comment: @oguzismail, sure thanks for letting me know, I was extra cautious so taken 2 of brackets, I added this solution too now in my post, thank you.

Comment: @VishalPatel, It is like I am simply substituting all occurrences of `] [` with `]` ORS(new line) `[`.

Answer (score 0):

assuring no space in string following 'get_ports'

```
$ echo '[get_ports {rdata[*]}] [get_ports {wdata[*]}] [get_ports {axirdata[*]}] [get_ports {raddr[*]}] [get_ports {waddr[*]}] [get_ports en] [get_ports {xyz[*]}] [get_ports err]'| sed -E 's/(\[get_ports\s+\S+)\s/\1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ \[get_ports/\n&/g' file
```

This inserts a newline before each string `[get_ports` and reproduces the results in the way you indicated.

To properly format the column, use:

```
 sed 's/ \+\(\[get_ports\)/\n\1/g' file
```

This replaces the leading spaces by a newline for each string.